# how to install and run a driver

Tags: driver, wdk, inf, minifilter

I've wrote a simple driver that only prints "Hello World" to the debug.
I used Visual Studio 2012 RC with WDK 8 in order to create an empty driver project and wrote the follwing code:

```
#include <NTDDK.h>

extern "C" NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT pDriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING pRegistryPath) 
{
    pRegistryPath = pRegistryPath; //unused
    DbgPrint("Hello World!");
    pDriverObject->DriverUnload = NULL;
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

I've compiled it to win7 x64.
I've read that in order to install and run this driver I need to write an .inf file, but I can't seem to manege that.
I took an example .inf file from WDK 8 and changed it to match my .sys file but it ruined my virtual box win7 x64 :-).
So I create a filter driver project in VS2012, took the .inf file and changed it to match my .sys file and when I installed it nothing happaned. I tried to run the new service it created with

```
net start MyDriver
```

but nothing was printed to the debug and also I don't see MyDriver in Computer->Manage->Services.
I'm using DebugView to see what is printed to the debug (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx).

Of course in time I would like to write a driver that acctualy does something, but meanwhile I just want to know how to run it.

The .inf file i took from VS2012 and changed is this:

```
;;;
;;; MyDriver2
;;;

[Version]
Signature   = "$Windows NT$"
; TODO - Change the Class and ClassGuid to match the Load Order Group value, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg462963
; Class       = "ActivityMonitor"                         ;This is determined by the work this filter driver does
; ClassGuid   = {b86dff51-a31e-4bac-b3cf-e8cfe75c9fc2}    ;This value is determined by the Load Order Group value
Class = "ActivityMonitor" 
ClassGuid = {b86dff51-a31e-4bac-b3cf-e8cfe75c9fc2}
Provider    = %ManufacturerName%
DriverVer   = 08/13/2012,1.0.0.0
;CatalogFile = MyDriver2.cat

[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir          = 12
MiniFilter.DriverFiles  = 12            ;%windir%\system32\drivers

;;
;; Default install sections
;;

[DefaultInstall]
OptionDesc          = %ServiceDescription%
CopyFiles           = MiniFilter.DriverFiles

[DefaultInstall.Services]
AddService          = %ServiceName%,,MiniFilter.Service

;;
;; Default uninstall sections
;;

[DefaultUninstall]
DelFiles   = MiniFilter.DriverFiles

[DefaultUninstall.Services]
DelService = %ServiceName%,0x200      ;Ensure service is stopped before deleting

;
; Services Section
;

[MiniFilter.Service]
DisplayName      = %ServiceName%
Description      = %ServiceDescription%
ServiceBinary    = %12%\%DriverName%.sys        ;%windir%\system32\drivers\
Dependencies     = "FltMgr"
ServiceType      = 2                            ;SERVICE_FILE_SYSTEM_DRIVER
StartType        = 3                            ;SERVICE_DEMAND_START
ErrorControl     = 1                            ;SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL
; TODO - Change the Load Order Group value, see http://connect.microsoft.com/site221/content/content.aspx?ContentID=2512
; LoadOrderGroup = "FSFilter Activity Monitor"
LoadOrderGroup   = "filter"
AddReg           = MiniFilter.AddRegistry

;
; Registry Modifications
;

[MiniFilter.AddRegistry]
HKR,,"DebugFlags",0x00010001 ,0x0
HKR,,"SupportedFeatures",0x00010001,0x3
HKR,"Instances","DefaultInstance",0x00000000,%DefaultInstance%
HKR,"Instances\"%Instance1.Name%,"Altitude",0x00000000,%Instance1.Altitude%
HKR,"Instances\"%Instance1.Name%,"Flags",0x00010001,%Instance1.Flags%

;
; Copy Files
;

[MiniFilter.DriverFiles]
%DriverName%.sys

[SourceDisksFiles]
MyDriver2.sys = 1,,

[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %DiskId1%,,,

;;
;; String Section
;;

[Strings]
; TODO - Add your manufacturer
ManufacturerName        = "Template"
ServiceDescription      = "MyDriver2 Mini-Filter Driver"
ServiceName             = "MyDriver2"
DriverName              = "MyDriver2"
DiskId1                 = "MyDriver2 Device Installation Disk"

;Instances specific information.
DefaultInstance         = "MyDriver2 Instance"
Instance1.Name          = "MyDriver2 Instance"
; TODO - Change the altitude value, see http://connect.microsoft.com/site221/content/content.aspx?ContentID=2512
;Instance1.Altitude      = "370030"
Instance.Altitude       = "370030"
Instance1.Flags         = 0x0              ; Allow all attachments
```

When I tried using wdreg.exe to install and run my driver it said "Failed locating Manufacturer section in INF file".
(from http://www.jungo.com/st/support/documentation/windriver/10.3.0/wdpci_manual.mhtml/dyn_windows.html)
I read a lot about .inf files (from some microsoft book and a lot of google) and I still don't know how to fix my .inf file.

If there is a simpler way to run my driver I would love to hear about it. Once I'll know how to run it, debuging the real product will be easy.

Thanks!

EDIT: I also singe the .sys file with Driver Signature Enforcement Overrider in Test Mode (http://www.ngohq.com/home.php?page=dseo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out Rohan was right.
I wasn't able to find a way to see the debug print in win7 (Rohan link is for vista), so I just created a file.

```
#include <wdm.h>
#include <Ntstrsafe.h>

extern "C" NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT pDriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING pRegistryPath) 
{
    UNICODE_STRING     uniName;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES  objAttr;

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&uniName, L"\\SystemRoot\\example12345.txt");
    InitializeObjectAttributes(&objAttr, &uniName,
                               OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE | OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE,
                               NULL, NULL);

    HANDLE   handle;
    NTSTATUS ntstatus;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK    ioStatusBlock;

    // Do not try to perform any file operations at higher IRQL levels.
    // Instead, you may use a work item or a system worker thread to perform file operations.

    if(KeGetCurrentIrql() != PASSIVE_LEVEL){
        return STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_STATE; 
    }

    ntstatus = ZwCreateFile(&handle,
                            GENERIC_WRITE,
                            &objAttr, &ioStatusBlock, NULL,
                            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                            0,
                            FILE_OVERWRITE_IF, 
                            FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT,
                            NULL, 0);


    CHAR     buffer[30];
    size_t  cb;

    if(NT_SUCCESS(ntstatus)) {
        ntstatus = RtlStringCbPrintfA(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "This is a test\r\n");
        if(NT_SUCCESS(ntstatus)) {
            ntstatus = RtlStringCbLengthA(buffer, sizeof(buffer), &cb);
            if(NT_SUCCESS(ntstatus)) {
                ntstatus = ZwWriteFile(handle, NULL, NULL, NULL, &ioStatusBlock, buffer, (ULONG)cb, NULL, NULL);
            }
        }
        ZwClose(handle);
    }


    pRegistryPath = pRegistryPath;
    pDriverObject = pDriverObject;

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

I used the same .inf I wrote in my question and then typed in the cmd

```
net start MyDriver2
```

and the file example12345.txt was created in C:/Windows.

Answer (score 2):

When you load/start the driver its loaded and functional in the kernel, so most likely your driver is loaded. But the `DbgPrint` message that you may not be seeing is because post Vista the debug messages logged with `DbgPrint` get filtered and not shown in the output.

Your can refer this to enable showing `DbgPrint` messages. [Getting DbgPrint Output To Appear In Vista and Later](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=295)

Another way is to use `DbgPrintEx` with appropriate Component and level.